# How to get all database which can be used in 'db_set_active'

Tags: 6, database, drush

Is there any way to list all possible database connections using Drush?
I am debugging an application where db connections are not written in settings.php and I'm not able to find all possible connections. And in code I can see

```
$database = db_set_active('test');
```

Is there any way to list the db connection names like test, test1, test2?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All database connection strings are in global $databases variable;

```
global $databases;
dpm($databases);
```

with drush:

```
drush php-eval 'global $databases; print_r($databases);'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Drush is able to do it, but in Drupal 6 you might try to look for the global variable `$db_url` in your code using grep or similar:

The "Set up multiple databases on the fly" section on the documentation below explains how the connections are set, for both Drupal 7 and Drupal 6 and older:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-within-drupal

For instance, for Drupal 6 you might find the following to define an alternative 'mydb' connection:

```
//set up the new database value
$db_url['mydb'] = 'mysql://user:pwd@localhost/anotherdb';
```